# Big picture on creating a Database for Social App

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a question regarding the most suitable way to organise datas when your app/product becomes used by more people.

Until now I've coded an Instagram-alike application for iOS which used Firebase to store data.

In particular I used "**Firebase Realtime Database**" with JSON data format to store all the datas.

My question here is: if I want to code an app which is potentially used by a lot of people, can I still use the same *Realtime database way of storing* or it's better if I use something else?

In particular I'm thinking about querying speed and sustainability of realtime database with a larger amount of data.

I'm a novice in this field and I don't know so much about Firebase so I'm sorry if my technical descriptions are raw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both databases will scale very well. If you have only simple querying needs than RTDB is fine. If your querying requirements are more sophisticated then Firestore. The other major factor is how usage of the two databases is charged for. You need to research that and then work out how the two cost models will work for your use case.